# HoverProperty inside canvas in javafx-8

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I want to draw a line in javafx-8 canvas such that when I keep my mouse over it, it should change its color and glow (if possible).
How do I do this?

Comment: Save all drawing operations and use the mousemoved/entered/exited events to determine, if the cursor is above a line. Redraw the content of the canvas accordingly...

Comment: This is going to be *much* easier if you use a scene graph approach, instead of a canvas. Do you need to use a canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't do this. 
In javafx, every `Node` is mouse aware, that is, you can track `MouseEvent` on a Node, but, unfortunately, drawings inside a `Canvas` aren't `Node`, rather they are mapping of pixels of that `Canvas`.

**Alternative :** 
 You can use an AnchorPane instead of canvas and have `Line` , `Circle` as its children.